# Importing External .jar file to Eclipse when the package name of the .jar file is (default package)

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar

I imported a jar file into Eclipse.

> So, in Eclipse by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, clicking Add External JARs and giving the Jar file.

Now I can see it in *"Referenced Libraries"* in *"Package Explorer"*.
In .jar files like *"common-math.jar"*, there are many packages like *"org.apache.commons-math"* and etc. that we can import these packages in our codes for using them.
But in the .jar file that I have added it, there is just one package that its package name is *(default package)*. How can I import it into my codes?

This code has an error:

> import (default package).xxxxxxxx;
>   Syntax error on tokens, Name expected instead
>   
>   [My Jar file](https://uploadfiles.io/ypcse)
>   
>   I see also [how to determine package name of a class in a jar file
>   Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812204/how-to-determine-package-name-of-a-class-in-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

(default package) means that the classes in the jar do not have any package. To import class SomeClass from the jar you just need

```
import SomeClass;
```

without qualifying it with a package name.

Comment: The hierarchy is: Referenced Libraries -> armstrong.jar -> (default package) -> Armstrong.class. The** import Armstrong;** cannot be resolved.